# How to count days excluding weekends and holidays but start day/end day can be weekends /holidays?

Tags: excel, macos, excel-formula

How to count days excluding weekends and holidays in excel. However, start day and end day can be weekends or holidays.

I have tried Networkdays function in excel using MAC. I also tried workdays function. And, i am new to this forum. Let me know if you are not able to understand anything.

`Start Date(E)  End Date (F)
2019-07-20 - 2019-08-01
2019-08-04  - 2019-08-06
2019-08-05  - 2019-08-07
2019-08-02  - 2019-08-07
2019-08-14  - 2019-08-20`

Holiday list

```
Date(K) Description   Day

8/12/19 - Eid - Monday
8/15/19 - Independence Day - Thursday
```

Excel formula:

```
= NETWORKDAYS(E2,F2,$K$7:$K$27)
```

Start date: Column E, End date: Column F, Holiday list: Column H

`output  expected output
9    8
2    1
3    1
4    2
4    2`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please clarify how would you calculate your `expected output`? I don't quite understand the logic behind these values. For example, first row (20/07/2019 - 01/08/2019) properly present the output of `9` as 20/21.07 are weekends, 22-25.07 are working days (Mon-Fri), 27-28.07 are weekends and then 29.07-1.08 are working days (Mon-Thu), giving us `9` in total. Your holidays list contains 2 holiday dates which do not fall on this period. It'd be easier to help once I understand your approach.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have made changes. So my question is that while calculating, it exclude Weekends and holidays. But start day or end date can be on weekends/ Holidays. if start day is 2019--08-04 and end day is 2019-08-06, it shows only difference.

Comment: Thanks for explaining - in the case of `2019-08-04 - 2019-08-06`, why the result is `1`? 4th is Sunday (weekend), 5th is Monday (working day) and 6th is Tuesday (working day) - shouldn't the result be `2`?

Comment: What day of the week are you using as day 1?

Comment: @JustynaMK thanks for your quick reply and your valuable efforts . Here we can use 2 approaches:

1) Including end date : If i include end date (2019-08-04 - 2019-08-06) then the result should be 2. 

2) Excluding end date: If i do not include end date (2019-08-04 - 2019-08-06) then the result should be 1.
ex- if i finish my work on 2019-08-04(Sunday) and i delivered the report for the same on 2019-08-12(Monday). So, here it should count only work day. Work days are Monday to Friday. Difference can be 5(excluded: 2019-08-12) or 6(included: 2019-08-12).

Comment: @SolarMike I am using Monday as Day 1

Comment: Just to be clear, is the system set to use Monday as day 1?

Comment: @SolarMike I am not clear about your question. I just use Networkdays function. If i use any other function then might i can take 2,3,4,5,6 for weekdays and (1,7) for weekend. Well, in the system, we did not define anything. There are just dates like start date- when i finished my work  and end date- when report got delivered for the same. And, we need to count days excluding weekends and holidays. It's like after completing the work, in how many business days we delivered the report.

Comment: I just added an answer - let me know if that works for you. I assumed that we are not only excluding weekends and holidays, but also start date and end date itself (as per your examples). Hope I understood it correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `NETWORKDAYS.INTL` to make sure that your weekend days are set to fall on Saturdays and Sundays.

For example:

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(E2+1,F2-1,1,$H$2:$H$3)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Justyna MK. I just want to know one thing that why you add "+1" to E2 and "-1" to F2. Also, why you use NETWORKDAYS.INTL function, instead of NETWORKDAYS.

In the another approach, when i was including end date, i used below formula:



=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(M2+1,O2,1,'Classification List'!$E$3:$E$23)

Comment: @ShwetaMehna good questions. I added +1 to E2 and -1 to F2 to make sure that Start and End Dates are not included in the calculations (e.g. a difference between 05/08 Mon and 07/08 Wed is 1 day, so Mon and Wed are excluded). `NETWORKDAYS.INTL` allow you to add one more parameter to the formula, called "weekend". `1` in the middle of a formula informs the function that it should follow "standard" weekend set-up (i.e. Saturdays and Sundays should be treated as days off). You can still use standard `NETWORKDAYS` formula instead if weekends in your system are set-up in the same manner.